# Limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\bigg(e^{-x\sqrt{n}}\Big(1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)^{-n}\bigg)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am having problems calculating this limit.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\bigg(e^{-x\sqrt{n}}\Big(1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)^{-n}\bigg)
$$
What I tried was to substitute
$$
-\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} =: \frac{1}{m}  \\
\implies m = - \frac{\sqrt{n}}{x} 
$$
So what I got is
$$
\lim_{m \to -\infty} \ln \biggl(e^{xm}\biggl(\Big(1 + \frac{1}{m}\Bigr)^{m}\Big)^{-m}\biggr)
$$
Then I continued but what I see, everything was flawed. I see the right part of the product should become $e$ to the power of something...
The result should be $\frac{x^2}{2}$, yet I can not find the way to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Taylor's formula at order $2$ for the log:
\begin{align}
\ln\biggl(e^{-x\sqrt{n}}\Bigl(1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr)^{-n}\biggr)&=- x\sqrt n-n\ln\Bigl(1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr) \\
&=-\frac x{\sqrt n}-n\biggl(- \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{x^2}{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\biggr)\\
&=\frac{x^2}2+o(1).
\end{align}

Comment: In fact, the bound can be improved to $\mathcal{O}\left( 1/\sqrt{n}\right)$.

Comment: What do you mean? Your $o(1/n)$ can be refined to $\mathcal{O}\left(1/n^{3/2}\right)$, so multiplying by $n$ gives $\mathcal{O}\left(1/\sqrt{n}\right)$

Comment: I used little o, not big O. (Taylor-Young's formula).

Comment: I understand, I'm just commenting that you can be even more specific about the error term.

Comment: Yes, but to determine the limit, it doesn't bring anything useful.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't help for the limit, but it is still generally relevant and the OP might be interested in it. Additionally, your comment saying that the bound cannot improved to $\mathcal{O}\left(1/\sqrt{n}\right)$ is false.

Comment: Yes, I has misread as a little o.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, but you might want to fix it.